# Material ui data grid custom pagination actions not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `Material-ui` `pagination` for creating custom pagination in `data grid`.

Here is my code for the custom pagination

```
export function CustomPagination() {
const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
const page = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageSelector);
const pageCount = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageCountSelector);
const classes = useStyles();

return (
    <Pagination
        count={2}
        page={page + 1}
        className={classes.root}
        // onChange={(event, value) => apiRef.current.setPage(value - 1)}
        renderItem={(item) => (
            <PaginationItem
                components={{
                    next: (props) => <Button onClick={item.onClick} {...props}>Next</Button>,
                    previous: (props) => <Button {...props}>Previous</Button>,
                }}
                {...item}
            />
        )}
    />
);
}
```

The problem is that next and previous buttons doesn't work, even when clicking the item it does nothing.

I tried to add and `onClick` in the next button but it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, in my datagrid i was setting page size to 5 (which was the number of all my data), and I hardcoded the pagination count to 2.